# How to create MongoID in android code?

Tags: java, android, mongodb, mongodb-query, gson

I am developing app with mongoDB support in android.
I want to create MongoID from java code and send it to my server.

Here is my code

I want to create this json

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59b7bcdf92e706382b00009f"),
"user_id" : "6bb82a99-bccd-4868-a799-55e7d28f969c",
"is_active" : false,
"_slugs" : [ 
    "aaa"
],
"facility_name" : "aaa",
"industry_id" : 1,
"old_industry_id" : 1,
"established_date" : "1994-06-01",
"summary" : "this is test",
"facility_website" : "www.xxx.com",
"contact" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("4637gdff92jhsgd378364y"),
    "info_type" : "PROFILE_INFO",
    "name" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "mobileNumber" : "xxxxxxxxx",
    "email" : "xxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    "shown_on_profile" : true
}}
```

But I am getting this Json from my java code.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59b7bcdf92e706382b00009f"),
"user_id" : "6bb82a99-bccd-4868-a799-55e7d28f969c",
"is_active" : false,
"_slugs" : [ 
    "aaa"
],
"facility_name" : "aaa",
"industry_id" : 1,
"old_industry_id" : 1,
"established_date" : "1994-06-01",
"summary" : "this is test",
"facility_website" : "www.xxx.com",
"contact" : {
    "_id" : "{}",
    "info_type" : "PROFILE_INFO",
    "name" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "mobileNumber" : "xxxxxxxxx",
    "email" : "xxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    "shown_on_profile" : true
}}
```

Problem is in "contact" object

Here is my java code

```
String _id = new JsonObject().toString(); // this is Gson.JsonObject() object
JSONObject contact = new JSONObject();
contact.put("_id", _id);
contact.put("info_type", "PROFILE_INFO");
contact.put("name", "User-1");
contact.put("mobileNumber", "xxxxxxxxxx");
contact.put("email", "xxxxx@gmail.com");
contact.put("shown_on_profile", true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @fandro i have solved my issue.

Server gives me mongoDB data like this

```
{"_id":{"$id":"59b7bcdf92e706382b00009f"}}
```

I can access this data using this code,
Here is my android Code

```
ID = jsonData.getJSONObject("_id).getString("$id");
```

For generating new ID i have created empty JSONObject in android and passed to my server.

```
_id = new JSONObject().put("$id", "");
```

On my server, i check id and if it is empty then i generate new MongoID form this code,

```
<?php
$_id = $_POST['_id'];
if ($_id['$id'] == "")
 $_id = new MongoID();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The MongoID is automatically generated by the server. What you need to do, is to send your contact without the MongoID. The server will insert the data in the database and return the MongoID of this element just created, and you can return the entire contact or just the MongoID to your Android app to use it.

Comment: But in my case there are many jsonObject.like JsonObject inside another JsonObject.

Comment: So you need to do it in multiple time : insert the object, get the objectID, send the second Object with the previous ID and get the Second Object ID...

Comment: @Mehul Did my solution help you ?

Comment: I have passed empty JSONObject as ID from android app, and then on server i have created new MongoID by using   "new MongoId()".

Comment: For efficiency: it's not required - but it allows us to POST and not worry about fetching the object from the backend - since we know what the _id will be a head of time.